# No Mostrar null al traer una consulta sin resultados en oracle

Tags: oracle-11g

tengo que realizar una consulta en oracle para que me traiga valores pero que no me traigan resultados NULL

```
SELECT RPAD(ESTADO, 20) AS ESTADO,
           RPAD(COUNT(*), 7) AS CANTIDAD,
           RPAD(A.RTAR, 7) AS RTAR
FROM Salarios
WHERE A.FECREGIS >= SYSDATE - 15 
     and B.MSISDN = a.codmin
     and A.estado <> 'ANULADO'
     and A.estado <> 'ANULADA'
     GROUP BY ROLLUP(ESTADO, RTAR);
```

el resultado de la consulta es algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quisiera es que no me traiga la fila cuando hay valores null,

muchas gracias

ejemplo 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi como esa imagen si havia una fila con valores null no la muestra y salta a la otra fila

muchas gracias

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres. Pon una salida esperada para los datos de ejemplo

Comment: añade el sql completo pues se nota que estas usando un join

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza `IS NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT RPAD(ESTADO, 20) AS ESTADO,
           RPAD(COUNT(*), 7) AS CANTIDAD,
           RPAD(A.RTAR, 7) AS RTAR
FROM Salarios
WHERE A.FECREGIS >= SYSDATE - 15 
     and B.MSISDN = a.codmin
     and A.estado <> 'ANULADO'
     and A.estado <> 'ANULADA'
     and A.RTAR IS NOT NULL,
     and ESTADO IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY ROLLUP(ESTADO, RTAR);
```

Comment: buenas tardes lo que quisiera es que ese valor no lo traiga si hay un valor null no lo imprima mas aqui con este ejemplo le estoy dando es un valor,

Comment: quieres que si uno de los campos es null no traiga esa fila?

Comment: asi es que si el campo es null no lo traiga la fila

Comment: actualice la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código requiere usar NVL o COALESCE para evitar ese output que dices.

`NVL (expr1, expr2)` permite reemplazar cualquier nulo con un valor por defecto.

Tu código se vería así:

```
SELECT RPAD(ESTADO, 20) AS ESTADO,
           RPAD(COUNT(*), 7) AS CANTIDAD,
           NVL(RPAD(A.RTAR, 7), "DEFAULT VALUE") AS RTAR
FROM Salarios
WHERE A.FECREGIS >= SYSDATE - 15 
     and B.MSISDN = a.codmin
     and A.estado <> 'ANULADO'
     and A.estado <> 'ANULADA'
     GROUP BY ROLLUP(ESTADO, RTAR);
```

`COALESCE( expr1, expr2, ... expr_n )` valida un conjunto de valores diferentes y retorna el primero que sea no nulo. Si la primera expresión es null, intentará con la segunda, etc.

Tu código se vería así:

```
SELECT RPAD(ESTADO, 20) AS ESTADO,
           RPAD(COUNT(*), 7) AS CANTIDAD,
           COALESCE(RPAD(A.RTAR, 7), "NO SALE NULL") AS RTAR
FROM Salarios
WHERE A.FECREGIS >= SYSDATE - 15 
     and B.MSISDN = a.codmin
     and A.estado <> 'ANULADO'
     and A.estado <> 'ANULADA'
     GROUP BY ROLLUP(ESTADO, RTAR);
```

Comment: buenas tardes lo que pasa es que ese resultado que salga null no se imprima ya que en este ejemplo y el de abajo se le da un valor al campo NULL